# PFXplus/powerflex .dat file converstion

Tags: database

I have the task of moving a PFXplus .dat files into a new Microsoft SQL server. The program in use was made probably around 2003 and hasn't been updated since. I see there is a PFXodbc driver for sale for $459 USD but i am not going to fork over that kind of money for a conversion job or even if that is the product i need. So simple question is there a way to convert the .dat PFXplus files to something usable? Anything in the Linux world perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to a powerflex runtime?  Or even better, a developer environment?  Or just the database?

You can use the powerflex provided reporter to create a CSV file, especially if the database is not too big.  It is a compiled program call "pfrep" and needs to be invoked using the runtime.

Do you know what version the data file is?  If it is Mark 1 (and maybe even Mark 2), then you could also look for a dataflex tool.  If it is Mark 3, then no.

Comment: yes i do, I found a program called pfxbrowser. It lets me over all the .dat files and copy and paste them into excel. i looked for pfrep but i could not find it. a second question is what are the .pr3 and .ptc files? are they important aswell?